# Android Query: grid display (images)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-query, aquery

I would like to display a number of images in grid format, 2 images per line. How do i do this with Android Query? Existing examples are insufficient and lack proper documentation...

activity_identify_animals.xml:

```
<ProgressBar                
    android:layout_width="15dip"       
    android:layout_height="15dip"
    android:id="@+id/progress" 
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"       
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"       
    android:layout_height="75dip"
    />
```

IdentifyAnimals.java:

```
package uk.ac.gla.serengeti.activities;

import com.androidquery.AQuery;

import uk.ac.gla.serengeti.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;

public class IdentifyAnimals extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_identify_animals);

        AQuery aq = new AQuery(this);

        aq.id(R.id.image).progress(R.id.progress).image("http://www.ibeta.eu/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/darthvader-design.jpg");
        aq.id(R.id.image).progress(R.id.progress).image("http://www.geekome.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/anakin-skywalker-voice-as-darth-vader.jpeg");
        aq.id(R.id.image).progress(R.id.progress).image("http://www.camelcitydispatch.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Darth-Vader-liking-villans-more-than-heroes-31394364-1280-960.jpg");
        aq.id(R.id.image).progress(R.id.progress).image("http://www.geekbinge.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Darth-Vader-Star-Wars.jpg");
        aq.id(R.id.image).progress(R.id.progress).image("http://static1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20111223224559/starwars/images/b/b0/DarthVader-CotF.jpg");
        aq.id(R.id.image).progress(R.id.progress).image("http://www.wallsave.com/wallpapers/1920x1200/darth-vader/460382/darth-vader-hd-free-for-460382.jpg");
    }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private void setupActionBar() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.identify_animals, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            //NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Reference: http://code.google.com/p/android-query/

Answer (score 4):

You can use a gridview with 2 columns

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridviewimg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="50dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" />
```

**EDIT**
Sure. You can write your own adapter class and fill in the array

```
public class ImageListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<String> imgPic;

public ImageListAdapter(Context c, List<String> thePic) {
    context = c;
    imgPic = thePic;
}

public int getCount() {
    if(imgPic != null)
        return imgPic.size();
    else
        return 0;
}

//---returns the ID of an item---
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

//---returns an ImageView view---
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    BitmapFactory.Options bfOptions=new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bfOptions.inDither=false;                     //Disable Dithering mode
    bfOptions.inPurgeable=true;                   //Tell to gc that whether it needs free memory, the Bitmap can be cleared
    bfOptions.inInputShareable=true;              //Which kind of reference will be used to recover the Bitmap data after being clear, when it will be used in the future
    bfOptions.inTempStorage=new byte[32 * 1024];
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    FileInputStream fs = null;
    Bitmap bm;
    try {
        fs = new FileInputStream(new File(imgPic.get(position).toString()));

        if(fs!=null) {
            bm=BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fs.getFD(), null, bfOptions);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
            imageView.setId(position);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 160));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        if(fs!=null) {
            try {
                fs.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return imageView;
}

}
```

Let me know if this is ok, else I can help you with the whole code as well.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button captureBtn = null;
    final int CAMERA_CAPTURE = 1;
    private Uri picUri;
    private DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    private GridView grid;
    private  List<String> listOfImagesPath;
    public static final String GridViewDemo_ImagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/GridViewDemo/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        captureBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.capture_btn1);
        captureBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        grid = ( GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridviewimg);

        listOfImagesPath = null;
        listOfImagesPath = RetriveCapturedImagePath();
        if(listOfImagesPath!=null){
            grid.setAdapter(new ImageListAdapter(this,listOfImagesPath));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (arg0.getId() == R.id.capture_btn1) {

            try {
                //use standard intent to capture an image
                Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                //we will handle the returned data in onActivityResult
                startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
            } catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
            //display an error message
                String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support capturing images!";
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        }

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //user is returning from capturing an image using the camera
            if(requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE){
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
                String imgcurTime = dateFormat.format(new Date());
                File imageDirectory = new File(GridViewDemo_ImagePath);
                imageDirectory.mkdirs();
                String _path = GridViewDemo_ImagePath + imgcurTime+".jpg";
                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(_path);
                    thePic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                    out.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.getMessage();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                listOfImagesPath = null;
                listOfImagesPath = RetriveCapturedImagePath();
                if(listOfImagesPath!=null){
                    grid.setAdapter(new ImageListAdapter(this,listOfImagesPath));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private List<String> RetriveCapturedImagePath() {
        List<String> tFileList = new ArrayList<String>();
        File f = new File(GridViewDemo_ImagePath);
        if (f.exists()) {
            File[] files=f.listFiles();
            Arrays.sort(files);

            for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++){
                File file = files[i];
                if(file.isDirectory())
                    continue;
                tFileList.add(file.getPath());
            }
        }
        return tFileList;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeGridLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridviewimg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="50dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/RelativeGridLayout" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/capture_btn1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Camera" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you provide me with code on how to dynamically display images from a string array or something like that?

Comment: I created the ImageListAdapter class - how do i populate the grid now? Sorry, I am completely new in Android Development :)

Comment: Again updated my answer with the whole source code. Happy Coding!!

Comment: i ran the app on my phone. However, it is somewhat different from what i expected. How do i make images appear as in this picture (2nd screen): https://raw2.github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/master/UniversalImageLoader.png I don't need to use a camera or anything like that. I supply URIs to images and they need to show up on a grid. How do i do that?

Comment: @martynas: I'm working on that. Will update you as soon as I complete.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45159/discussion-between-vikramv-and-martynas)